# Ajax filtering not works in Tabulator

Tags: filter, tabulator

I have this code

```
        $("#example-table").tabulator({
        height: '78vh',
        layout: "fitColumns",
        ajaxConfig: "POST",
        ajaxURL: "/Home/TestJson",          
        ajaxProgressiveLoad: "scroll",
        ajaxFiltering: true, 
        columns: [
            { field: "id", title: "id", headerFilter: true},
            { field: "name", title: "name"  },
        ],
        });
```

but it does not work when I type something in column filter. my JSON is correct and I return last_page parameter. When I type something it pass the filter parameter an the server returns correct JSON but tabulator is not able to refresh the data based on the new received json.
please help. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you've read and looked for `tabulator` documentation?

Comment: Yes, do u have a clue?

Comment: you would have to paste more data. What does your `/Home/TestJson` return?

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with version 3.5 and has been fixed in today's 4.0 release :) If you update your Tabulator source files you should be all sorted